# Efficient way of writing the elements of a quotient group.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, normal-subgroups, cyclic-groups, quotient-group

I am considering the normal subgroup $H=\langle[28]\rangle$ of the additive group $\mathbb{Z}_{220}$. I want to obtain the elements of the quotient group $\mathbb{Z_{220}}/H$.

Since $H=\langle14[2]\rangle$, we have that $|H|=\frac{220}{\gcd(220,14)}=55$. Therefore, by Lagrange's theorem, $|\mathbb{Z}_{220}/H|=\frac{|\mathbb{Z}_{220}|}{|H|}=\frac{220}{55}=4$. So, I know that $\mathbb{Z}_{220}/H$ has four elements and one of them is $[0]+H$.

The problem I encounter is that, for example, $[0]+H$ is the same as $[28]+H$. Because of this, I have to be careful when writing the other three elements to make sure that I am not making the mistake of writing twice the same element because it is written in two ways that "look different".

If I wrote explicitly all $55$ elements of each element (maybe I should call it class or coset) of the quotient group then I would be sure I am not making that mistake. But this does **not** look very **efficient**. I was wondering if there might be some **clever way of choosing the representative** of each class so as to make sure there are no hidden repetitions.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the quotient of a cyclic group of order $n$ by a cyclic subgroup of order $m$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/458808/what-is-the-quotient-of-a-cyclic-group-of-order-n-by-a-cyclic-subgroup-of-orde) . The image of $[1]$ will generate the four cosets you need.

Comment: I think $H=\langle[4]\rangle$, and the other quotient elements are $[1]+H, [2]+H,$ and $[3]+H$